# Question regarding Kunneth isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are smooth compact oriented manifolds, with $dim Y=r$. Then we know that $H^r(Y, \mathbb{R}) \simeq \mathbb{R}$. If $p: X \times Y \rightarrow X , q: X\times Y \rightarrow Y$ are the two projections, we have the Kunneth isomorphism:

$\bigoplus_{i=0}^{k}H^i(X,\mathbb{R})\otimes H^{k-i}(Y,\mathbb{R}) \xrightarrow{\sim}H^k(X\times Y,\mathbb{R})$

Now suppose $k\geq r$. Then we also have a 'pushforward' (also called Gysin) map in cohomology, which essentially comes from the pushforward in homology and Poincare duality:

$H^k(X\times Y, \mathbb{R}) \xrightarrow{p_*} H^{k-r}(X,\mathbb{R})$

My question is: Is the Gysin map $p_*$ equal to the projection $H^{k}(X\times Y,\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow H^{k-r}(X,\mathbb{R})\otimes H^r(Y,\mathbb{R}) \simeq H^{k-r}(X,\mathbb{R})$ under the Kunneth isomorphism above?

I'm finding it difficult to verify it directly. Any help would be welcome.

Comment: I think you are able to answer this question by looking at the level of singular chains and cochains and using explicit representations of all the maps. The isomorphism in Poincare duality is given by what's called the cap product with the fundamental class of the manifold btw. And it has a nice representation on singular co/chains. And the Künneth map also has a nice representation on the level of chains.